# Flutter + Firebase updateDisplayName when creating account with Email and Password

Tags: firebase, authentication, dart, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new to Flutter and really, really new to firebase.

I'm trying to create a user via the createUserWithEmailAndPasswordMethod.
I've successfully created on, but I'm trying to improve it by allowing the user to enter the desired username and setting said username to the displayName attribute.

My code is as follows:

```
    _createUser() async {
UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
updateInfo.displayName = _usernameController.text;

FirebaseUser user = await _auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailController.text,
  password: _passwordController.text,
)
    .then((user) {
  user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
});
print('USERNAME IS: ${user.displayName}');
}
```

The problem is when I run the app it always throws this exception:

```
NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'displayName' was called on null.
```

Every time I debug the `user` variable keeps showing as null as well, even though the user is created and I can print the email and password!

I guess the problem is that `Firebase user` is null, but even if I move the `print('USERNAME IS: ${user.displayName}');` to right after `updateProfile` the same happens.

Hope you guys can help!
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, what worked for me was this: I had to call the reload() method to get the new user information after the updateProfile(). After some changes the method looks like this:

```
  _createUser() async {
UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
updateInfo.displayName = _usernameController.text;

await _auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailController.text,
  password: _passwordController.text,
)
    .then((user) async {
  await user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
  await user.reload();
  FirebaseUser updatedUser = await _auth.currentUser();
  print('USERNAME IS: ${updatedUser.displayName}');
  Navigator.of(context).push(
    MaterialPageRoute<Map>(
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return Posts(_googleSignIn, updatedUser);
      },
    ),
  );
}).catchError((error) {
  print('Something Went Wrong: ${error.toString()}');
});
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't use await and then together. Take a look at my code. It will work.

Comment: This worked for me, but the `user.reload()` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 4):

You should not use await and then together. await is a substitute for then method.

```
_createUser() async {
await _auth
    .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
  email: _emailController.text,
  password: _passwordController.text,
)
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

  UserUpdateInfo updateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();
  updateInfo.displayName = _usernameController.text;
  user.updateProfile(updateInfo);
  print('USERNAME IS: ${user.displayName}');
}
```

Comment: No, the same thing happens.

Comment: @DiogoMelo sorry, I missed something big. I fixed my code now. When you are using await, you don't need to use then()

Comment: I found a way to make it work, but it actually only worked after I added await.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still searching, this is the working solution in 2021.

```
UserCredential userCred = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

await userCred.user.updateProfile(displayName: "Your Name");
```